# Depth of binary tree with few single children

Tags: binary-trees

The node of a binary tree is called a *single child* if it has a parent but does not have a sibling. The root is by definition not considered a single child.

> Let $T$ be a binary tree of size $n$, and let $k$ be the number of vertices in $T$ that are single children.
> Is it true that if $\frac{k}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}$
> then the height of $T$ is $O(\log n)$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Why worry about the case of the root ? Does that make a difference ?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a tree with *no* single children which has height $(n-1)/2$:
[image: Path tree].